# Qwik Prod. Vercel Runtime Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error loading dynamically

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, vercel, qwik

I am having these problems in console when I try to submit a form to my MongoDB with

import {formAction$} from "@modular-forms/qwik";

```
> XHRPOSThttps://www.nexasoft.dev/customer-form/q-data.json?qaction=id_vI9xZZ8C8Hw[HTTP/2 404 Not Found 194ms] 
> GEThttps://www.nexasoft.dev/build/q-cdf5d4d1.js
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module: https://www.nexasoft.dev/build/q-cdf5d4d1.js
```

that file q-cdf5d4d1.js load this:

```
import{O as o,u as e,c as r,_ as s}from"./q-7a45fca9.js";import{F as a}from"./q-063603b2.js";const i=a(e("s_eiZe9BHsm7A")),m=o(r(()=>s(()=>import("./q-fe6aefcc.js"),["build/q-fe6aefcc.js","build/q-7a45fca9.js"]),"s_3OBzwgZDJ5o"));export{m as default,i as useServerTimeLoader};
In development everything works great. My deploy was hosting with Versel. Doing https://vercel.com/integrations/mongodbatlas Integration.
```

My DbConection

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const DB_USER = `${import.meta.env.VITE_DB_USER}`;
const DB_PASSWORD2 = `${import.meta.env.VITE_DB_PASSWORD2}`;
const DB_NAME = `${import.meta.env.VITE_DB_NAME}`;
const MONGO_HOST = `${import.meta.env.VITE_MONGO_HOST}`;
const options = {
dbName: DB_NAME,
user: DB_USER,
pass: DB_PASSWORD2,
};
const dbPromise = await mongoose.connect(
MONGO_HOST,
options
);
export default dbPromise;
```

Send my form to mongo DB.

Minimal Reproduction Code. I create a new Qwik app, with react and static adapters. In header click link to visit Form route.

[Project Repository](https://github.com/Maikpwwq/qwik-ssg-modular-forms)

[Vercel Deployment](https://qwik-ndv3c8fj3-maikpwwq.vercel.app/)

[Vercel Project](https://vercel.com/maikpwwq/qwik-app/)